# How to improve Cassandra Performance

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm testing Cassandra Performance with C# .net Single threaded application. While Inserting multiple records with my application, I found that the Cassandra Write Speed is just 470 Records/Sec.
How to improve the Writing Speed of my application on Cassandra Database?

Comment: Are you sure you want your application to be single threaded ?

Comment: Yes, I required single thread application only.